# create and modify json string

Tags: php, jquery, json

This is my first time, that I am working with json.
This is the situation:

I get data via php from my mysql database and store this into a php array:

```
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT chatToken, lastMessageID FROM chat")
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();

while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
   $chatData[$row->chatToken] = $row->lastMessageID;
}
```

Now I would like to get this in a jquery function:

I tried this:

```
var chatData = '<? echo json_encode($chatData); ?>'
myFunction(chatData)

    function myFunction(chatData) {

       console.log(chatData)
       // OUTPUT: {"tgv5pxfjsDGXA3JcEYVM":88,"a9gxNZ7HzfcJXQsWCtAp":99}

       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "getData.php",
          data: 'chatData='+chatData,
          dataType: 'json',
       }).done(function(result) {

          console.log(result);
          // Please look the Picture below for output

       })

    }
```

**Output of console.log(result)**

[image]

**getData.php**

```
<?php

$chatData = json_decode($_POST['chatData']);
$message = array();

foreach($chatData AS $chatToken => $lastMessageID) {

   $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `chatToken` = ? AND `ID` > ?") 
   $statement->bind_param("ss", $chatToken, $lastMessageID);
   $statement->execute();
   $result = $statement->get_result();

   while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

      $message[] = array(
                           "lastMessageID" => $row->ID, 
                           "chatToken" => $row->chatToken,
                        );
   }

   $statement->close();

}

echo json_encode($message);


?>
```

So far so good.
But now I would like to replace / update my `var chatData`:

```
{"tgv5pxfjsDGXA3JcEYVM":88,"a9gxNZ7HzfcJXQsWCtAp":99}
```

with values from the `result`. Finally it have to be:

```
{"tgv5pxfjsDGXA3JcEYVM":188,"a9gxNZ7HzfcJXQsWCtAp":99}
```

How can I realize it?

Comment: `chatData` is a string, so you can either use string replace or you can parse it into an object, make the change and convert it back.

Comment: and how can I parse it into an object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chatData is JSON (a string), you can:

- parse it into an object `JSON.parse`
- make the change
- convert it back to a string `JSON.stringify`

```js
// result from ajax call, jquery converts this from the php json to an object/array
var result = [{chatToken:"tgv5pxfjsDGXA3JcEYVM",lastMessageID:188}];

// string from `var chatData = <?php ...` as JSON
var chatData = '{"tgv5pxfjsDGXA3JcEYVM":88,"a9gxNZ7HzfcJXQsWCtAp":99}'; 

// convert string to object
var data=JSON.parse(chatData); 

// use the first result array ([0]) chatToken to update chatData
data[result[0].chatToken] = result[0].lastMessageID;

// convert back to JSON (string)
chatData = JSON.stringify(data);

// show result
console.log(chatData);
```

---

In your case, I'd recommend converting `chatData` to an object at the start

```
var chatData = JSON.parse('<? echo json_encode($chatData); ?>');
```

and then using it as an object, then convert to json(string) only as needed (in the ajax post)

```
data: 'chatData='+JSON.stringify(chatData),
```